# Unable to Access Request Parameter in SpringMVC Controller while redirecting to URL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, url-parameters

I am having a form which submits new articles to my controller.

**JSP Page:**

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post"
    action="/articleViewer">
<div class="control-group" style="margin-top: -5px;">
    <label class="control-label text-info" for="commentContent"><strong>Post
            Comment</strong></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="FormElement" name="area2" id="commentContent"
        style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 90%;">Post</button>
</form>
```

**Controller Method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/articleViewer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveArticleComment (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Principal principal, ModelMap map) throws ServletException, IOException{
    //processing request
    System.out.println("Link : "+Path.Jsp.ARTICLE_VIEWER_PAGE);
    return Path.Jsp.ARTICLE_VIEWER_PAGE; //this ARTICLE_VIEWER_PAGE = /articleViewer
}
```

Now from the above controller method I wanna redirect to another method where I want to pass 
currently saved article id as `http://<myurl>/article?articleId="xyz".`

Here is my get method code for handling the redirect.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/articleViewer", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String articleViewer(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal,
        ModelMap map, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws DatabaseException {
        //I wanna access article id here.
    return Path.Jsp.ARTICLE_VIEWER_PAGE;
}
```

I wanna know how could I access that passed request parameter in above method?

Comment: This means you have lost one important parameter in the url.

Comment: Yess After submiting  the form I lost paramenter and it shows that page bloank bcz it takes ArticleID as input param

Comment: Yeah, you didn't post the jsp, impossible to answer.

Comment: That's quite expected. Post parameters are sent in the request body, and not in the query string. You should save the comment and then redirect. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Yes I have Done it already plz see

Comment: @JB Nizet.. and How i suppose to do so I tried return "forward:/articleViewer"; it insert 500 more comments to my aticleComment table

Comment: A forward and a redirect are completely different things. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting

Comment: Unable to implement it what you told...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit the action url without parameter, or use `hidden` field for this purpose then you should return that parameter back as a result. So, you don't get it lost, or redirect to the page where the parameter is not needed anymore. To pass parameter in the url use

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/articleViewer?varArticleID=94">
```

Comment: By using this I got in URL /articleViewer?varArticleID=79 but its not Calling my Get method code

Comment: I mean after this url also my form is Blank no article no comments

Answer (score 1):

I Resolved it by using Redirect attribute in return ...

```
return "redirect:/articleViewer?varArticleID="+getVarArticleID();
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you need the page like as after submitting change the action value of form like

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post"
    action="/articleViewer?varArticleID={yourArticleid}">
```

Also after submit you need

```
return Path.Jsp.ARTICLE_VIEWER_PAGE+"?varArticleID="+request.getParameter("varArticleID");
```

Comment: My Method i.e saveArticleComment  is mapped to this method How should i map it to /articleViewer?articleId=94

Comment: after returning this it gives ERror 404

Comment: Its shows Error 404 when i use return Path.Jsp.ARTICLE_VIEWER_PAGE+"?varArticleID="+request.getParameter("varArticleID");

Comment: When i use only <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/articleViewer?varArticleID={yourArticleid}"> and URL localhost:8888/articleViewer?varArticleID=79  after posting it blank bcz it is calling post method not get it should call get method with that URL

Comment: Ok Iam not strong in spring methods.I think the method for getting the data's for above url should write in GET method where you handling the reuest.

Comment: I method in my Qu only @RequestMapping(value="/articleViewer", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String articleViewer(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal,
        ModelMap map, HttpServletResponse response) is used for method and post is used for posing as per Qu details

Comment: I throws Runtime i have already tried it..... I m also new to spring ... i think i have to find my way by my own